# Get access to the elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, forecasting

I want to get some particular elements in a list which is returned by the forecast function in R.

My data is like this

```
Point     Forecast       Lo 80     Hi 80        Lo 95     Hi 95
111       69894.82  62433.7449  77355.89   58484.0929  81305.54
112       69894.82  60130.1979  79659.43   54961.1218  84828.51
113       69894.82  58274.6632  81514.97   52123.3264  87666.30
114       69894.82  56677.0955  83112.53   49680.0575  90109.57
115       69894.82  55252.8108  84536.82   47501.8019  92287.83
```

I want to get the number in column "Forecast".

I used the following code to create my data:

```
myts is some time series data
fit <- auto.arima(myts)
res <- forecast(fit, 677)
```

The name of my data is res which is a list of 10.
The result of dput(res) is as the following:

```
-2443.82541262374, -3956.5563302119, 1335.8788362195, 3804.02514978909, 
-1364.6312311184, -360.502517865796, -286.138018093465, -2804.55786143203, 
-1201.73015351274, -1085.1353062962, 8688.02102637354, -5767.08772503892, 
7292.94004476998, -2310.33192585826, -1329.76851485969, -4561.07364095336, 
2552.742451461, 3299.51706250617, 2447.80597742078, 15969.1761900118, 
-12064.25481109, -4186.66470081449, -6343.95400053521, 3822.10952263371
), .Tsp = c(1, 110, 1), class = "ts")), .Names = c("method", 
"model", "level", "mean", "lower", "upper", "x", "xname", "fitted", 
"residuals"), class = "forecast")
```

Comment: unique(dataframe$Forecast)

Comment: @CnrL Hi, thanks for your quick reply. However, my data is actually a list not a dataframe. My list's name is res. I tried res$Forecast and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `lapply(res, "[", , 2)`

Comment: You really should share the output of `str(res)`. So you have have a list with a single data.frame in it? Because what you posted sure looks like a data.frame

Comment: @RichardScriven I also tried res[["Forecast"]], it also returns me a NULL. My data is a list not a dataframe

Comment: Well then show us an example of the list please

Comment: Please provide `dput(res)`

Comment: Will be best to see dput(res) output as David suggests, but maybe you have a list of dataframes?  If so, maybe unique(res[[1]]$Forecast)?

Comment: Arrrgh. In R dataframes ARE lists. I'm guessing you have a list of lists (with perhaps one member) and need res[[1]][['Forecast']]

Comment: > str(res)
List of 10
 $ method   : chr "ARIMA(0,1,1)                   "
 $ model    :List of 16
  ..$ coef     : Named num -0.156
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "ma1"
  ..$ call     : language auto.arima(x = structure(list(x = structure(c(83567L, 80244L, 72295L, 54048L, 54545L, 59733L, 58903L, 58147L, 56693L,  54580L, 51685L, 56660L, 62156L, 61190L, 57174L, 55582L, 56860L, 56784L, 58537L, 64653L, 62645L, 74966L, 62491L, 60712L,  ...
  ..$ series   : chr "myts"
  ..$ model    :List of 10
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "forecast"

Comment: res[[1]]$Forecast; I got the following error
Error in res[[1]]$Forecast : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Please add the output from dput(res) to the question (i.e. not here in the comments)

Comment: @CnrL Thanks! this works perfect. Could you please tell me how do you figure that out?

Comment: If you would like to contribute an answer, do not put it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.numeric(res$mean)
```

Will do the job.

As per your comment, so `Forecast` is the actual forecast and it is not always just the mean.

Consider the following example using a data set taken from [here](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html)

```
library(forecast)
births <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/data/nybirths.dat")
birthstimeseries <- ts(births, frequency=12, start=c(1946,1))
fit <- auto.arima(birthstimeseries)
res <- forecast(fit, 12)
plot(res)
```

[image]

As you can see from this plot, the forecast isn't just the mean, and the `auto.arima` fitted a seasonal model

If you'll inspect  `res$mean`, you will see that the numbers are different

```
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct
1960 27.69056 26.07680 29.26544 27.59444 28.93193 28.55379 29.84713 29.45347 29.16388 29.21343
          Nov      Dec
1960 27.26221 28.06863
```

As per your last comment, in order to inspect the "guts" of an unknown (to you) R object it is always preferable to start with `class(res)`, `str(res)` and finally `attributes(res)`. The later will reveal you all the attributes that this object contains:

```
attributes(res)
## v$names
##  [1] "method"    "model"     "level"     "mean"      "lower"     "upper"     "x"         "xname"    
##  [9] "fitted"    "residuals"

## $class
##  [1] "forecast"
```

So now you can investigate `res$method` or `res$model` and finally, the one you were looking for `res$mean`

Comment: unique(res$mean) is a better solution. Since your command gives me [1] 69894.82 69894.82

Comment: @trying, not it's not. It is better in this specific case because your forecast just fitted the mean, but it is not always that way and some times it won't be the same number over all rows

Comment: Could you tell me how do you figure this answer? I'm confused about the data structure in R